# How to Change Data in a ListView stored in XML or TXT?

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, visual-studio-2012

I am currently trying to write myself a management application. I have been doing a lot of reading on how to Write and Read from/to a text document via a ListView. I have so far been able to write data to a text file, however, I want to be able to change that data. For example, I have a ListView displaying :

Object = Apples 
 - Quantity = 5

And instead of adding an entirely new item, I want to increment one apple. The reason for doing this is so that I can call the same data from another form (Within the same application). Like have my initial ListView displaying Apples and Number of Apples, but then being capable of changing that number through a separate Options form. I've heard of maybe XML, but I do not know how to use IO.stream with XML (Or how you would even organize it for editing certain items)

Any ideas, or guidance? I'm completely stumped..

EDIT :
Perhaps some use of Arrays? Not sure..

Comment: You seem to be using VB.NET, yet you tagged the question VBA. Is this an error, or are you actually using VBA?

Comment: In general, I'd advise to try to think about this a bit differently. You are not reading and writing from a file via a ListView, you should be reading a list of something (Product?) from a file (which should be an object defined in your model), displaying / editing these in the ListView, and saving that list back to the file. Your question is very broad, though - it will be difficult to give you a quick and to the point answer.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Well, basically, my end goal is to be able to change an item value within the ListView. My problem is that all of the searches turn up info on how to Add items, but none on how to change an existing one. If you could explain to me how one would Change an item within the ListView, i would be grateful. (As per my above example, with changing values of the item "Apple" within the list.)

Comment: You cant directly modify the listview in your manner that you want; hence that why it is a listview. Yes you can add AND update the list, but not what you are trying to do... What you can do is: Have a DataGridView control, write your data and then save it as an XML file for future modifications... Then you can pull this in anytime and update it and then save it.

Comment: Ok, I will give that a shot. If all else fails I suppose I can try SQL

Comment: In above post I explain what you can do. Here's the question: "What have you done?"

Comment: I will give just a tiny sample for you to work with... It will suit you just fine to get started... Give me a minute or so...

Comment: Ok I posted a sample to get you started, it only saves the data and you can keep updating this file ... It doesn't show how you can retrieve this data, but that is quite simple when you come to that.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a DataGridView to a Form. Then name it to something, in this example mine is dgvInvoice. Once you have the control on the form you need to add your columns to that DataGridView. You can do that by clicking on the control and at the top right click the black play like button and click on "add columns" or something like that. When you add your columns on the right side of the screen make sure to give them a design name; this is a reference to your column. Once this has been completed you can start on your saving to XML...

Here is a small sample to get you started...

First create an empty XML file anywhere you want to...Nothing has to be in the file just an empty XML file. Then follow below...

```
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.Xml
 Imports System.Text

 Public filePath As String = "PUT YOUR PATH TO XML HERE" - 'YOUR FILE PATH TO YOUR XML FILE GOES HERE'

 Private Sub btnSaveGrid_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveGrid.Click
      CompileGrid() 'Using another sub to actually do the saving...
 End Sub

 ***************************************************************************
```

NEXT SUB....

```
 Private Sub CompileGrid()

    'Get the XML from the table!'
    Dim dt As New DataTable("invoices") 'YOU CAN ADD WHATEVER NAME YOU WANT HERE'

    'THIS WILL ADD YOUR COLUMN NAMES TO THE TABLE'

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvInvoice.ColumnCount - 1
        dt.Columns.Add(dgvInvoice.Columns(i).Name, GetType(System.String))
    Next

    'THIS WILL ADD YOUR ROWS DATA TO THE TABLE'        

    Dim myrow As DataRow
    Dim icols As Integer = dgvInvoice.Columns.Count
    For Each drow As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgvInvoice.Rows
        myrow = dt.NewRow()
        For i As Integer = 0 To icols - 1
            myrow(i) = drow.Cells(i).Value
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(myrow)
    Next

    'NEXT LETS WRITE THE DATA TO AN XML FILE'

    dt.WriteXml(filePath)


End Sub
```

Now if you go and open that file up in notepad or whatever you want to use, you will see your data in this file. Now dont modify this because you can write over this automatically everytime you do it.